# Networkconfig on Debian-based Linuxes

Tags: ubuntu, networking, debian, interface

Question: I've some Debian or Ubuntu based servers here with

```
allow-hotplug eth0
```

and some with

```
auto eth0
```

in /etc/network/interfaces. What is the difference between them? If I'm correct, both are bringing up the interfaces during startup and if a cobel is pluged in. Right?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

allow-hotplug allows you to plug in a new network device (say, turning on a network card, PCMCIA cards, etc.).

auto is just auto-detection of the port being plugged in IIRC to bring the interface online.

Answer (score 1):

One potential serious consequence of allow-hotplug instead of auto is that allow-hotplug interface usually do not come up after issuing a

/etc/init.d/network restart

they go down but don't come up again which leaves you with a "down" interface.